# Ayuda con un ciclo

Tags: php, laravel, ciclos

Tengo el siguiente código que sólo guarda la primer imagen del select, como desarrollo el ciclo para que guarde todas las imagenes seleccionadas:

```
if(Input::file('img'))
    {
        $subir = $this->file->upload('categorias',Input::file('img'));
        $categoria->img = $subir->id;
    }
```

El form simplemente es el siguiente:

`<input type="file" name="img" id="file1" multiple="multiple">`

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que estas usando Laravel, seria bueno que detallaras esa información en tu pregunta para que le sea de utilidad a mas personas.

En cuanto a tu pregunta, puedes implementar así:

```
$categoria = [];
foreach(Input::file('img') as $imagen) {
    $subir = $this->file->upload('categorias',Input::file('img'));
    $categoria[]->img = $subir->id;
}
```

> Según se muestra en este sitio de ayuda: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/multiple-upload-with-laravel?page=1

Comment: Hola, lo probé como me indicas y sale el siguiente error: Trying to get property of non-object   $subir = $this->file->upload('productos/',Input::file('img'));
        $producto[]->img = $subir->id;